# Best way to add css classes or html text in Rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

Rails devs! I got a "best practice" question here. So I'm dealing with something very simple but that it's enough for me to understand.

I got this header partial in my Rails views, and I'm using devise to authenticate users. I'm displaying in modals the **login form** and my **register form**, all good there. In my `html.erb` that would look like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-body">
                <%= render '/devise/sessions/new'%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registerModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-body">
                <%= render '/devise/registrations/new'%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I don't know if I'm being picky here but, is there a way I can reduce both of these two partials in to one? Like for example:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="{dynamicId}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="{dynamicModaltitle}" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-body">
                <%= render '{dynamic partial view}'%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Probably that is not the correct syntax but I just want to make a point on what I want to achieve. I'm a very try believer of DRY code where I know there is a way to manage unrepeated code including in views itself. I will appreciate your help to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track: You can move the HTML part that is identical into a partial like this

```
# in app/views/shared/_modal.html.erb
<div class="modal fade" id="<%= name %>Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="<%= name %>ModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-body">
                <%= yield %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and than render that model like this:

```
<%= render "shared/modal", name: 'login' do %>
  <%= render '/devise/sessions/new' %>
<% end %>

<%= render "shared/modal", name: 'register' do %>
  <%= render '/devise/registrations/new' %>
<% end %>
```

Note how the local variable `name` is used in the partial to generate the correct `id` and `label`. And how the `yield` in the partial will be replaced with the HTML provided in the block of the `render` call.

See [Using Partials to Simplify Views](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials-to-simplify-views) from *Layouts and Rendering in Rails* from the *Rails Guides*.

Comment: I would use `<%= tag.div id: "#{ name }Modal", ...  do %>` instead of ERB interpolation in the middle of an attribute.